List all ways to draw n numbers with replacement out of m < n values (i.o.w.: all partitionings of a set of size n into m distinct subsets) in R
In a simulation study, I need to generate all distinct ways to generate a sequence of m numbers between 1 and n (n>m) such that the sum of the numbers is n, i.e.
nums <- c(n_1, n_2, ..., n_m)

with the constraints
min(num) > 0 & sum(nums) == n

In other words: the possible partitionings of a set of n elemnts into m distinct subsets. I know that the number of such partitions is the "Stirling number of the second kind", which makes this infeasible for large n, but I will need it for small n.
Note that this a different problem from finding all permutations, which is answered in this thread. It is instead about partitioning.

From the partitions package, would partitions::compositions(5) do the trick for you? (for similar functions, maybe have a look at the GitHub page)

The combinat package does not provide a function for this, but the suggestion by @felix-jassler works. I can subsequently filter out the columns containing zeros by indexing with colSums(part==0) == 0.

@cdalitz Just added an answer, if min(num) > 0 you can set include.zero=FALSE :)

From the partitions package (GitHub), partitions::compositions(n, m, include.zero) should do the trick. Here, n would represent what each vector should sum up to, m the number of elements of that vector, and include.zero=FALSE ensures that there's no zeros.
partitions::compositions(n=5, m=2, include.zero=FALSE) |> t()
# [1,] 4 1
# [2,] 3 2
# [3,] 2 3
# [4,] 1 4

